# Rayleigh quotient for non symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

For a given real symmetric matrix $M$ and nonzero vector $x$, the Rayleigh quotient is defined as:
$$R(M,x) = \frac{(Mx,x)}{(x,x)}$$
Why is the Rayleigh quotient only defined for symmetric matrices? If $M$ is an arbitrary matrix in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, is the Rayleigh quotient of $M$ the least squares best approximation to the eigenvalue corresponding to $x$?
I think $M$ has to be symmetric: the normal equations for $\underset{\alpha \in \mathbb R}{\min}\|Mx - x\alpha\|$ is $$x^Tx\alpha = x^TMx \implies \alpha = \frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}.$$
This is equal to $R(M,x)$ iff $M$ is symmetric?

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't define $R(M,x)$ that way, but the result will be the same as $R((M+M^\top)/2, x)$. So the Rayleigh quotient just tells you about the symmetric part of your matrix.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, can you explain why in this case $\alpha = R((M+M^T)/2,x)$?

Comment: Because $x^\top M^\top x = x^\top M x$.

Answer (score 2):

For a pair $(A,B)$ of matrices, the generalized Rayleigh quotient is defined as

$$R(A,B,x) = \frac{(Ax,x)}{(Bx,x)},$$

provided that $(Bx,x) \ne 0.$